# How to execute smart contract from offchain-worker?

Tags: ink, smart-contract, pallet-contracts, offchain-worker, offchain

Would it be possible to execute smart contract call from an offchain-worker, either using `ink!` or `pallet-contracts`?

Can someone please help me to provide the solution? is there any example?